# What does `peer` and `origin` means in term of Istio Policy?

Tags: security, authentication, oauth-2.0, istio

I am a newbie in security thing. I just learnt about Istio and read about its security aspect. The authentication defined in Istio (https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.authentication.v1alpha1/) has some basic terms that I don't know the meaning: `peer` and `origin`.

Can anybody explain it what is it and what's the difference? 
My guess:

- peer = for service to service communication, hence the peer identity is a machine-based identity (service account attached to that machine)
- origin = for end-user to service communication. Usually it is human-based identity, but also can be a service account identity (like bot user).

Is my understanding correct? Perhaps somebody can explain and elaborate more about them?

Thanks,
Agung

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - peer = for service to service communication, hence the peer identity    is a machine-based identity (service account attached to
>     that
> - machine) origin = for end-user to service communication. Usually it      is human-based identity, but also can be a service account identity
>     (like bot user).

Yes, you understand it right.
`Peer` is for service --> service and `origin` is mostly for end-user to service communication. But it can also be used for service account identities.

peers:

> List of authentication methods that can be used for peer
>   authentication. They will be evaluated in order; the first validate
>   one will be used to set peer identity (source.user) and other peer
>   attributes. If none of these methods pass, and peerisoptional flag is
>   false (see below), request will be rejected with authentication failed
>   error (401). Leave the list empty if peer authentication is not
>   required

origins:

> List of authentication methods that can be used for origin
>   authentication. Similar to peers, these will be evaluated in order;
>   the first validate one will be used to set origin identity and
>   attributes (i.e request.auth.user, request.auth.issuer etc). If none
>   of these methods pass, and originisoptional is false (see below),
>   request will be rejected with authentication failed error (401). Leave
>   the list empty if origin authentication is not required.

Also good to read [Increasing Security with a Service Mesh](https://www.infoq.com/articles/istio-security-mtls-jwt) article.